# C++ Program with GUI to capture using remotely placed camera and read uncompressed TIFF Image

Tags: c++, image, networking, image-processing

I want to do this operations using C++ on image:
Image Frame1 is used for displaying Original Image
and Image Frame 2 is used for displaying the action performed.

- Sharpen the Image
- Convolution(overloading: FFT,
  Other)
- Blur the Image (Programmable
  rectangular Seed)
- Histogram
  •Programmable image Contrast and Brightness
- Mean and Standard Deviation of Image
- Rotate image by programmable angle
- PDF of a Signal acquired through
  ADC

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with QT and OpenCV combination. I used QT+OpenCV combination on still images. You can easily create GUI's with QT and with OpenCV you can make  video capture and other image processing approaches on each frame.

Comment: Yes i think of that but its restricted to do with Eclipse as QT is no more open source.